# CPU Usage from Linux then using it in a arithmetic expression

Tags: linux, bash, arithmetic-expressions

I have this line in bash,

cpu=`` `top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print $1}' ``

Thats working as I want it if I echo it but when used in the next line as part of a equation.

`joulesFinal=$(($joules2*$cpu))`

I get the error from system

`arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "6*93.4"`

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash arithmetic is integer only.  It won't accept fractional numbers like 93.4.
You need to pipe the expression through `bc`.

```
joulesFinal=`echo $joules2 * $cpu | bc`
```

Comment: or upgrade to [zsh](http://zsh.sf.net/): `echo $((4.2 + 6.7))` produces `10.9`. ;)