# Backticks vs braces in Bash

Tags: bash, command-substitution

When I went to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693415/cpu-usage-from-linux-then-using-it-in-a-arithmetic-expression), I was going to use the `${}` notation, as I've seen so many times on here that it's preferable to backticks.

However, when I tried

```
joulesFinal=${echo $joules2 \* $cpu | bc}
```

I got the message

```
-bash: ${echo $joules * $cpu | bc}: bad substitution
```

but

```
joulesFinal=`echo $joules2 \* $cpu | bc`
```

works fine. So what other changes do I need to make?

Comment: For simple arithmetic, just use Bash's built-in facilities.  `joulesFinal=$((joules2 * cpu))`

Comment: @tripleee the original question involved non-integer arithmetic, so the built-in wouldn't work

Comment: Related post: [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts).

Answer (score 161, accepted):

The ``` `` ```  is called Command Substitution and is equivalent to `$()` (parenthesis), while you are using `${}` (curly braces).

So all of these expressions are equal and mean "interpret the command placed inside":

```
joulesFinal=`echo $joules2 \* $cpu | bc`
joulesFinal=$(echo $joules2 \* $cpu | bc)
#            v                          v
#      ( instead of {                   v
#                                 ) instead of }
```

While `${}` expressions are used for variable substitution.

Note, though, that backticks are deprecated, while `$()` is POSIX compatible, so you should prefer the latter.

---

From `man bash`:

> **Command substitution** allows the output of a command to replace the
> command name. There are two forms:
>
> ```
>           $(command)
>    or
>           `command`
> ```

Also, ``` `` ``` are more difficult to handle, you cannot nest them for example. See comments below and also [Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: I've investigated it, and I have to admit that backtics are indeed compatible with the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) standard. However, it is still true that bash deprecated them, and that `$()` is better to handle (+1)

Comment: ... also found no "real" deprecation in the [bash project](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete), meaning a hint that backtics will be removed in upcoming versions. Seems using `$()` is just the *preferred way*. sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: No problem at all, @hek2mgl , I find it very interesting. I have sometimes read here in SO that it is deprecated, so it is common to think so (I even thought that). But for me, the most important reason to use `$()` instead of ` `` ` is the fact that with the first you can nest, while the second does not allow it.

Comment: now we know :) .. Yeah, the possibility of nesting them with need to escape is a big advantage of `$()`!

Comment: Even if you don't nest, backticks are easily overlooked in quite many console fonts. `$()` much less so.

Comment: You can nest with "\`\`", it's just ugly. "echo \`echo \\`echo abc\\`\`" works.

Answer (score 48):

They behave slightly differently in a specific case:

```
$ echo "`echo \"test\" `"
test

$ echo "$(echo \"test\" )"
"test"
```

So backticks silently remove the double quotes.

Comment: Interesting example.  I suspect that the contents of $() is run before the outer string has it's special characters handled as opposed to the case in which backquotes are used.  If you want to use backquotes and have quotes persist, `echo "\`echo \\"test\\"\`"` will work as the bash slash escape character needs to be escaped for outer string parsing for it to persist for the inner command.

Comment: The difference is due to the difference, how they both handle escaping. This is also different: `"echo \`\$var\`"` and `"echo $($var)"`

Answer (score 5):

`${}` refer to Shell parameter expansion. Manual link:https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

> The ‘$’ character introduces parameter expansion, command
> substitution, or arithmetic expansion. The parameter name or symbol to
> be expanded may be enclosed in braces, which are optional but serve to
> protect the variable to be expanded from characters immediately
> following it which could be interpreted as part of the name.
>
> When braces are used, the matching ending brace is the first ‘}’ not
> escaped by a backslash or within a quoted string, and not within an
> embedded arithmetic expansion, command substitution, or parameter
> expansion.

```
FULLPATH=/usr/share/X11/test.conf_d/sk-synaptics.conf
 echo ${FULLPATH##*/}
echo ${FILENAME##*.}
```

First echo will get filename. second will get file extension as per manual *${parameter##word}* section.

---

```
$(command)

`command`
```

refer to command substitution.

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell
> environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard
> output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted.**

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html