# Return number of files in a directory to a variable in a shell scrtpt

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I need the number of total files in a directory and want to use this number in a shell script.
I tried this in terminal and it works fine:

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

It just prints the number of files, but I want to assign the returned number to a variable in my shell script, I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
numberOfFiles = find . -type f | wc -l;
echo $numberOfFiles;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the output of a command, you need to use the `var=$(command)` syntax:

```
numberOfFiles=$(find . -type f | wc -l)
echo "$numberOfFiles"
```

Problems in your current approach:

```
numberOfFiles = find . -type f | wc -l;
             ^ ^
             | space after the = sign
             space after the name of the variable
      no indication about what are you doing. You need $() to execute the command
```

You are currently trying to execute the `numberOfFiles` command with the following parameters: `= find . -type f | wc -l;`, and it is clearly not what you want to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, when assigning an command output to a variable you need to use `. Or you can also use `$(command)`. Both are right way.

```
numberOfFiles=`find . -type f | wc -l`;
echo $numberOfFiles;
```

Comment: backticks are quite outdated and `$()` is preferred, since you can nest them. See [Bash Backticks vs Braces](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22709371/1983854) for example.

Comment: yeah I know, still sometimes I can't refrain from using back-ticks, cause used it lots of time since studying, it's became a habit. Thanks for the link @fedorqui it's quite informative.