# Bash simple sentence

Tags: bash

I am creating a new file and trying to print out my current directory within a sentence. I want it to look like "My current directory is /.../.../.../". What can I do to get the output I am looking for? Any help or support is much appreciated.

```
bash3.2$ sciript test1.script
bash3.2$ cat -n > test1.1
```

I have tried doing several different things like...

```
echo "My current directory is" $pwd
echo "My current directory is $pwd"
pwd
...........
```

Answer (score 2):

`pwd` is a command, not a variable, so you can't get its value using `$pwd`.

You're looking to [perform *command substitution*,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22709390/139010) so use backticks or `$(...)` to evaluate commands in a double-quoted string:

```
echo "My current directory is `pwd`"
# or
echo "My current directory is $(pwd)"
```

More: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48393/4515

Comment: Bash sets `$PWD`, so that's another option.

Comment: My only problem is when I create (cat -n > test1.1) If I type in echo" My current directory is `pwd`" It types that exact sentence literally. The only way I can get it do show up outside of the specified file is "ctrl-d" then type it.

Comment: @yellowantphil, huh? Bash doesn't get between `cat` and its stdin in this use case (or in the case of any other command run without input redirection applied). Now, if it were `cat <<EOF` (but not `cat <<'EOF')`, _then_ you'd get interpretation of the heredoc before it was passed to `cat`, but this isn't that case in the context of this question.