# In BASH, does a variable set to a command run the command and save the output as the variable?

Tags: bash

Forgive my being a noob. Essentially I'm asking if `foo=ls`, when called, would input "ls" or if it would have run ls and then, when called, it would have already run ls, and just use that output. I'm assuming it is the former, in which case, how could you save the output of ls as a variable?

Comment: This question can teach you a little about ways of doing that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709371/bash-backticks-vs-braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo=$(ls)`

You can use `$(your command)` to get the output of your command.

In fact, you can't use `foo=ls` to make `foo` an alias of `ls`. You have to write `alias "foo"="ls"` so that you can use `foo` as `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

`var=ls` is a variable that,  when expanded,  is `ls`.  Thus after expansion, bash will execute the command ... if it's the first token in the line.   The following are two very different things.

```
var=ls
$var #very different from the below
echo $var
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foo=ls
```

does not run ls, it just assigns string 'ls' to variable foo.

```
foo=`ls`
```

runs ls and capture its output (stdout to be precise) to variable foo.