# Failing to redirect error message in my command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm a rookie in bash scripting, and here's basically my bash script:

```
Z=`diff -Z $ref_out $exec_out | grep "[<>]" | wc -l` 2>/dev/null
if [ $Z -gt 0 ]; then
echo "*** testcase: [ stdout - FAILED ]"
else
echo "*** testcase: [ stdout - PASSED ]"
fi
```

I would like to suppress the error message from diff such as:

```
diff: No such file or directory
```

This could either result from no $ref_out or $exec_out file, though I'm redirecting to /dev/null, this error message still shows up.
Any help?

Comment: why don't you check if $ref_out or $exec_out exist before you use `diff` ?

Answer (score 3):

You need `diff`'s stderr to go to /dev/null, so it should instead be:

```
Z=`diff -Z $ref_out $exec_out 2> /dev/null | grep "[<>]" | wc -l`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your redirection isn't working because it is being applied to the parent shell, not the subshell that runs the pipeline.

If you want to send the stderr of a bunch of commands to /dev/null, you could do it this way - I am using `$()` instead of [backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22709371/6862601):

```
Z=$( { diff -Z $ref_out $exec_out | grep "[<>]" | wc -l; } 2>/dev/null )
```

Here, `2>/dev/null` applies to all the commands inside `{ }`.

---

There are many issues in your code.  You could rewrite it in a better way:

```
if diff -Z "$ref_out" "$exec_out" 2>/dev/null | grep -q "[<>]"; then
  echo "*** testcase: [ stdout - FAILED ]"
else
  echo "*** testcase: [ stdout - PASSED ]"
fi
```

- `grep -q` is a better way to do this check and you won't need a `wc -l` unless you want to know the exact number of matches
- you need to quote your variables
- `if` statement can include commands; you don't need to capture the output in order to use it in the if statement

You can use [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) to validate your shell script and see if you are making the usual mistakes that can break your code.