# How to find the particular files in a directory in a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to find the particular below files in the directory  using find command pattern  in  shell script .

The below files  will create  in the directory "/data/output" in the below format every time.

```
 PO_ABCLOAD0626201807383269.txt
 PO_DEF 0626201811383639.txt
```

So I need to find the above txt files starting from "PO_ABCLOAD" and "PO_DEF"  is created or not.if not create for four hours then I need to write in logs.

I written script but I am stuck up to find the file "PO_ABCLOAD" and "PO_DEF format text file in the below script.

Please help on this.

What changes i need to add in the find command.

My script is:

```
file_path=/data/output

PO_count='find ${file_path}/PO/*.txt  -mtime +4  -exec ls -ltr {} + | wc -l'

if [ $PO_count == 0 ]
then
   find ${file_path}/PO/*.xml -mtime +4 -exec ls -ltr {} + > 
 /logs/test/PO_list.txt

fi
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the forum. To search for files which match the names you are looking for you could try the `-iname` or `-name` predicates. However, there are other issues with your script.

#### Modification times

Firstly, I think that `find`'s `-mtime` test works in a different way than you expect. From the manual:

> -mtime n
>        File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.

So if, for example, you run

```
find . -mtime +4
```

you are searching for files which are *more than four days old*. To search for files that are more than four *hours* old, I think you need to use the `-mmin` option instead; this will search for files which were modified a certain number of *minutes* ago.

#### Command substitution syntax

Secondly, using `'` for command substitution in Bash will not work: you need to use backticks instead - as in

```
PO_COUNT=`find ...`
```

instead of

```
PO_COUNT='find ...'
```

Alternatively - even better (as codeforester pointed out in a comment) - use `$(...)` - as in

```
PO_COUNT=$(find ...)
```

#### Redundant options

Thirdly, using `-exec ls -ltr {} +` is redundant in this context - since all you are doing is determining the number of lines in the output.

So the relevant line in your script might become something like

```
PO_COUNT=$(find $FILE_PATH/PO/ -mmin +240 -a -name 'PO_*' | wc -l)
```

or

```
PO_COUNT=$(find $FILE_PATH/PO/PO_* -mmin +240 | wc -l)
```

If you wanted tighter matching of filenames, try (as per codeforester's suggestion) something like

```
PO_COUNT=$(find $file_path/PO/PO_* -mmin +240 -a \( -name 'PO_DEF*' -o -name 'PO_ABCLOAD*' \) | wc -l)
```

#### Alternative file-name matching in Bash

One last thing ... 
If using `bash`, you can use brace expansion to match filenames, as in

```
PO_COUNT=$(find $file_path/PO/PO_{ABCLOAD,DEF}* -mmin +240 | wc -l)
```

Although this is slightly more concise, I don't think it is compatible with all shells.

Comment: Using `$()` instead of backquotes is a good practice. See [Backticks vs braces in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22709371/6862601).

Comment: @codeforester: Thanks for suggestion. I have just updated my answer.

Comment: `\( -iname 'PO_DEF' -o -iname 'PO_ABCLOAD*' \)` to be safer.

Comment: @codeforester: Yes, I was going to suggest that as well. Might update my answer - although I wonder if it is already long enough as is.

Comment: In AIX i am getting error -iname is not a valid option.

Comment: @Maxtech: What shell are you using? If you are using Bash you can try the 'alternative file-name matching' option I just added.

Comment: @Maxtech: Also, what is your `find --version`?

Comment: will check it.Thanks

Comment: @Maxtech: You probably don't need `-iname`. Just use `-name` instead. I have updated my answer.