# Sourcing a bash script and assigning a value to variable via backtick execution

Tags: bash, variables, backticks

I have a strange problem with bash that I cannot explain.

I created the script test.sh which contains the lines:

```
export TEST_HOME=`ls -d $HOME`
echo $TEST_HOME
if [ "$HOME" = "$TEST_HOME" ]
then
  echo "Equal"
else
  echo "Not equal"
fi
```

Now if I source test.sh:

```
$ . test.sh
```

the output is

```
/home/sven
Not equal
```

However, if I make it executable and run it as a normal script:

```
$ test.sh
```

the output is

```
/home/sven
Equal
```

Any explanation how this behavior is explained? I am using RedHat 5.

Best regards,

Sven

Comment: I'm getting "Equal" in both cases. Cannot reproduce the behaviour :-(

Comment: Thanks for checking. So it looks like this is just due to some installation parameter settings.

Comment: What does `echo $HOME` say in both cases?

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709371/backticks-vs-braces-in-bash regarding `$()` or "``"