# How to replace "\n" string with a new line in Unix Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix

Cannot seem to find an answer to this one online...

I have a string variable (externally sourced) with new lines `"\n"` encoded as strings.

I want to replace those strings with actual new line carriage returns.  The code below can achieve this...

```
echo $EXT_DESCR | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

But when I try to store the result of this into it's own variable, it converts them back to strings

```
NEW_DESCR=`echo $EXT_DESCR | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'`
```

How can this be achieved, or what I'm I doing wrong?

Here's my code I've been testing to try get the right results

```
EXT_DESCR="This is a text\nWith a new line"
echo $EXT_DESCR | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'

NEW_DESCR=`echo $EXT_DESCR | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'`
echo ""
echo "$NEW_DESCR"
```

Comment: How are you inspecting `NEW_DESCR`?

Comment: This works for me: `test=$(echo "testing\nthis" | sed 's/\\n/\n/g') && echo "$test"` consider switch from backticks to `$()` to capture output to a variable.

Comment: The comment by @JNevill identifies the problem.  See also the answer by @Gunstick to [Backticks vs braces in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22709371/4154375).  In summary: expressions inside backticks (but not `$()`) have a level of quoting removed before they are executed.

Comment: Is this an XY Question for "how do I turn a JSON string into plaintext?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need for `sed`, using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ foo='1\n2\n3'; echo "${foo//'\n'/$'\n'}"  
1
2
3
```

---

With `bash 4.4` or newer, you can use the `E` operator in [`${parameter@operator}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ foo='1\n2\n3'; echo "${foo@E}"
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thank you!!  Parameter Expansion was originally what I wanted to do when I started yesterday, but could not wrap my head around it!  This is awesome!

Answer (score 8):

Other answers contain alternative solutions. (I especially like the parameter expansion one.)

Here's what's wrong with your attempt:

In

```
echo $EXT_DESCR | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

the sed command is in single quotes, so sed gets `s/\\n/\n/g` as is.

In

```
NEW_DESCR=`echo $EXT_DESCR | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'`
```

the whole command is in backticks, so a round of backslash processing is applied. That leads to sed getting the code `s/\n/\n/g`, which does nothing.

A possible fix for this code:

```
NEW_DESCR=`echo $EXT_DESCR | sed 's/\\\\n/\\n/g'`
```

By doubling up the backslashes, we end up with the right command in sed.

Or (easier):

```
NEW_DESCR=$(echo $EXT_DESCR | sed 's/\\n/\n/g')
```

Instead of backticks use `$( )`, which has less esoteric escaping rules.

Note: Don't use `ALL_UPPERCASE` for your shell variables. `UPPERCASE` is (informally) reserved for system variables such as `HOME` and special built-in variables such as `IFS` or `RANDOM`.

Comment: This is great info!  I was looking for the parameter expansion initially myself!

Comment: I'd include http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082, especially for the **see also** :)

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what exactly you need it for:

```
echo -e $EXT_DESCR
```

might be all you need.

From echo man page:

-e
    enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Answer (score 3):

This `printf` would do the job by interpreting all escaped constructs:

```
printf -v NEW_DESCR "%b" "$EXT_DESCR"
```

`-v` option will store output in a variable so no need to use command substitution here.

Problem with your approach is use of old back-ticks. You could do:

```
NEW_DESCR=$(echo "$EXT_DESCR" | sed 's/\\n/\n/g')
```

Assuming you're using `gnu sed` as `BSD sed` won't work with this approach.

Comment: I didn't know about `%b`, nice one +1.