# Difference between ` and $ in UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

In Unix we have 2 ways to execute a command and capture its output in a variable:

1.)

```
x=`wc-l`
```

2.)

```
x=$(wc -l)
```

Can anyone help me understand the basic difference between the two, and when to use which syntax.

Comment: see [command substitution in bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution), back tick is older syntax and parentheses are easier to use with nesting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709371/backticks-vs-braces-in-bash

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Also: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03