# how to pass container id to docker exec through output of another cmd

Tags: shell, docker, ssh

i want to pass docker container id from output of another linux command

example (as pseudo-code):

```
save output of docker ps cmd to a file
docker ps > docker.log
grep only container id : awk 'FNR == 2{print $1}'
```

now i want to pass the output of `awk` cmd to `docker exec`

like `docker exec -it awk 'FNR == 2{print $1}' /bin/bash` (i am not able to pass container id through cmd)

this is to automate a process that needs `ssh` in `docker` containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something like this:

```sh
docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep dac705114996 | awk '{print $1}') /bin/sh
```

As you can see, in order to pass the `container-id` to the `docker exec` cmd, you need to substitute the `container-id` with `$(command that extracts the container-id)` [Command Substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709371/backticks-vs-braces-in-bash) (more [official docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html))

Comment: i wanted to run a shell script to do ssh in docker container regard less of container id. 
i adopted your solution and changed a little bit and works for me  
thank you @azbarcea

`docker exec -it $(docker ps | aws 'FNR ==2 {print $1}') /bin/bash`