# How to pass linux command to bash execution as command line argument?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Please, don't be too much strict to my question and even it's a structure (maybe I have structured the sentence in a wrong way), as I am learning bash scripting. So the goal is to pass variable, which on his turn is another command (eg. `ls -l | wc -l`), to script execution.
To pretend this is my command from my terminal

```
./variables.sh (ls -l | wc -l)
```

As you may guess, this doesn't work and throws an error

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ls'

So the question is - how to do it right?

Comment: Put it in quotes, not parentheses

Comment: so, if for example `ls -l  | wc -l` returns the number 7, you want your script to execute as `./variables.sh 7`? If that is the case, all you need is `./variables.sh $(ls -l | wc -l)` although others will warn you that piping output of `ls` can cause hard to diagnose problems. Good luck.

Comment: that might depend on how "primary" script expect arguments, but check man of xargs

Comment: Pass them in double quotes and run via `eval $*`. But it’s highly not recommended to do this way.

Comment: @shellter thanks, that works fine.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: I'm glad my idea helped. I hope that you see now how you can write a better question next time. Don't make people guess about what you are trying to do, please! ;-) OK? Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround your variable with backtick ` :

```
./variables.sh `ls -l | wc -l`
```

As mentioned in comments, you can achieve this by below command as well :

```
./variables.sh $(ls -l | wc -l)
```

Comment: `$()` is better than backticks.

Comment: @Barmar what's the difference between them?

Comment: `$()` nests better. It's also more readable IMHO, you won't confuse them with single quotes.

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan Good read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709371/backticks-vs-braces-in-bash , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: @Pacifist_AWS thanks, good one )