# How to pass an argument in a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, arguments, rsync

I am running the script

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

billseqno=`sqlplus -s /@prod <<EOF
set heading off
set serveroutput off
select max(billseqno) from bc_run where control_group_ind is null;
EOF`

echo "$billseqno"


shark=`rsync --stats --dry-run -ax bill@shark:/home/$billseqno/ /home/temp/ | grep -i "number of files transferred" | cut -c30-`
```

whereby `$billseqno` represents a folder name and which is a number.

My problem is that the value of `$billseqno` is not passed to the `rsync` path.

Any suggestions what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use

```
shark=$(rsync --stats --dry-run -ax bill@shark:/home/"${billseqno}"/ /home/temp/ | grep -i "number of files transferred" | cut -c30-)
```

and have a look into

- [Backticks vs braces in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709371/)
- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to change your SQL query to be as below :

```
billseqno=$( sqlplus -s replacethis/@prod <<-EOF
    set pagesize 0;
    set feedback off;
    set verify off;
    set heading off;
    select max(billseqno) 
    from bc_run 
    where control_group_ind is null;
    exit;
EOF )


shark=$(rsync --stats --dry-run -ax bill@shark:/home/"$billseqno"/ /home/temp/ | grep -i "number of files transferred" | cut -c30-)
```